# Input with both Radio and checkbox characteristics

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

I am looking to design a input field such that it will obey radio buttons characteristics as well as checkbox characteristics.

The requirement is that there are some bars, to which when I click,  a text "hello" will be shown adjacent to that bar. and when I click on another bar, the "hello" text from the previous bar should hide and the clicked bar's "hello" text should be visible.

This is happening in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk9y4o15/)

```
label {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span {
    display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
:checked + span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
```

But what I want is each bar should act as toggle button to show/hide the "hello" text. I can achieve this if I use checkboxes instead of radio button but I will lose the behavior which I achieved above using radio buttons.

I am looking for a pure css solution.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

This is what I want. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk9y4o15/4/)**

But using only css.

Comment: Radio Cum? uhh.. What's that?

Comment: @Mr_Green Im confused, why would you not just use checkboxes? Radio boxes are single choice... Thats the point of them.

Comment: It seems there is no way.. I will delete this question in 5 mins.

Comment: @Ruddy if I use checkboxes, I will not be able to hide that text when I click another bar.

Comment: You could wrap each radio button in `form` so they act alone. I don't see this being possible using CSS only (I could be wrong so maybe worth leaving this question for a little longer).

Comment: i would say either use checkboxes or radio, and complete next part using script

Comment: @Mr_Green In that case I think I misunderstand what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dk9y4o15/3/

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz The OP did say using CSS only, using Javascript I'm sure the OP could easily do it them selfs.

Comment: hey @Ruddy thats why i didnt post this as answer, i m trying to get info from OP, is that the same thing he wants using css

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz Pshh, you didn't make that very clear did you! Carry on :D

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz ruddy is right, I can do it using jquery. but looking for css only solution. btw, in your fiddle, when I click on another bar, the text adjacent to other bar should hide.

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz check my edit. I will end up using the same if it is not possible using css in this modern world :(

Comment: Both examples behave same for me.

Comment: @Morpheus the first example is missing toggle behavior.

Comment: Second as well. Testing in Chrome

Comment: @Morpheus Come to this [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can afford to edit html and really can't afford to use any javascript at all you can do it by using `<input type='reset' />`, but this is a hacky way to handle such functionality - javascript should **always** be your first choice for such tasks.

```css
label {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span {
    display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
   }
input[type="reset"] {
    position: absolute;
    border:0;padding:0;margin:0;background:transparent;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: none;
}
:checked + span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
:checked + span + input[type="reset"] {
    display: block;
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test"></input> <span>Hello</span>
    <input type='reset' />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test"></input> <span>Hello</span>
    <input type='reset' />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test"></input> <span>Hello</span>
    <input type='reset' />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test"></input> <span>Hello</span>
    <input type='reset' />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test"></input> <span>Hello</span>
    <input type='reset' />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test"></input> <span>Hello</span>
    <input type='reset' />
</label>
</form>
```